# displaying data from a mysql table in html

Tags: php, html

I need to display mysql data in a html table. The method that I am currently using was a bit of a quick fix and is a bit clumsy, can anyone explain the proper way to do this?

```
<?php

$a= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM document WHERE email='$semail' ORDER BY  id ASC LIMIT 
");    
$b= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM document WHERE email='$semail'  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT
1 OFFSET 1 ");   
$c= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM document WHERE email='$semail'  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT
1 OFFSET 2 "); 

if ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($a));
if ($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($b));
if ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($c));

?>

<html>
  <table>
     <tr>  
       <td><?php echo $a['col1']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $a['col2']; ?></td>
     </tr>   
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $b['col1']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $b['col2']; ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $c['col1']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $c['col2']; ?></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: With that said, are you sure your queries are returning results?  Try try taking out the `if`s and just do a `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($a))` to see if anything is queried correctly

Comment: it works fine but it just seems like inefficient code

Comment: Is you table generating the data? Seems fine to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for on building your table:

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM document WHERE email='$semail' ORDER BY id ASC";
$items = $MySQL->getSQL($command);

echo "<html><body>";

if(count($items) > 0)
{
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($items as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $column){
            echo "<td> {$column} </td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else echo "NONE";

echo "</body></html>";
```

My getSQL function is:

```
function getSQL(/*STRING*/ $query)
        {
            $newarray = array();
            $result = mysql_query($query, $this->dbConn);

            if(!$result) die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            { 
                array_push($newarray, $row);
            }

            return $newarray;
        }
```

This will get everything from your query and build a table for it. You wont have to break it into pieces as it appears you have done as it supports all column & row sizes.